# How to share utility class among iOS projects?

Tags: ios, xcode

Should I create iOS 8 new feature called Frameworks / Extensions to share a simple Utility class used among more projects?

How do you share common application logic? I thought I will just drag a swift textfile in projects without checking `Copy items if needed` checkmark. Am I doing right?

I found here a promising tutorial with fancy inbuilt animation: http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

And this youtube video tutorial is useful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely do that about have a common file in a folder and imported in several projects but that doesn't look like a good approach.

- What if you start to make breaking changes over time? Some projects can work and others not,
- What was the last version that worked for each project?. As is shared changes happens to all project without fine grain control
- Would anybody that work in a team with you be able to compile the project? How you share with other people those not copied files necessaries to run the project.

So my answer would be to use a new repo for the shared code and make a framework from it and share the frameworks across projects tracking the version. Or if you prefer use git submodules or git subtree.

Finally, [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) with the new `use_frameworks!` feature in the 0.36 version solve all these problems for swift (as they did before for Objective-C) making possible do to your our public or private frameworks in swift as you could share static libraries before.